# How to intercept and respond to traffic in python or Java

Tags: python, java, networking

For a POC, I want to use python or java to sniff network traffic packets, and respond to specific ones. Something like a MITM attack. The library should be able to capture ICMP packets as well. I've looked at jpcap but it can only sniff packets and can't be used to send your own response to packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) library can:

- Sniff packets in just about any format
- Work in promiscuous mode *(i.e. sniff traffic not addressed to you).*
- Create and Inject packets in just about any format, *(including invalid formats).*
- Be used to respond to specific packets by sending responses or otherwise.
- You can even build your own protocols!
- *Much more...*
- It works on Linux, Windows, OSX *and on most Unixes with libpcap*
- Price: $0.00 (Free)
- Open Source:  GPL-2.0 License